# Killed by signal 11(SIGSEGV) and/or 6(SIGABRT)

Tags: c++, shortest-path, sigabrt, segmentation-fault, maze

I'm having this slight issue with my program. In Visual Studio 2012 it runs fine, but if I compile it with G++ (yes, for reasons above me, I have to use it to compile), the error signals 11(SIGSEGV) or 6(SIGABRT) get triggered depending on the input. This is a programming excercise and I have another program (on an online server) which tests my program with 10 different inputs. As I said, the program compiles and works well while using Visual Studio 2012.

About the program:
It finds the shortest path from starting point (x,y) to a number of exits (the amount of exits are irrelevant and differ. There could be only 1 exit or there could be 200).
The input goes as follows:

```
7 12          // maze height and width
##########.#  //
#..........#  //
#.###.######  //
#..X#.#.....  // the maze blueprint
#.###.#.####  //
#..........#  //
############  //
```

And my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef struct _laby_t {
    int h, w;
    char **pohja; // 'pohja' is finnish and means layout
} laby_t;

typedef std::vector<int> monovector;
typedef std::vector< std::vector<int> > bivector;

laby_t *laby_allocate (int r, int c)
{
    laby_t *laby;
    int i;

    laby = new laby_t[sizeof (laby_t)];
    laby->pohja = new char *[r];
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        laby->pohja[i] = new char[c];
    }
    laby->h = r;
    laby->w = c;

    return laby;
}

int wander(int y, int x, laby_t *&_laby, int goals)
{
    laby_t *laby = _laby;
    int found = 0, depth = 0, min_path = 1000000;
    bool b = 0;
    bivector openList;
    monovector start; start.push_back(y); start.push_back(x);
    bivector closedList;

    openList.push_back(start);

    while(found < goals)
    {

        y = openList.back()[0]; x = openList.back()[1];
        monovector r; r.push_back(y); r.push_back(x); closedList.push_back(r);
        openList.pop_back();
        if(laby->pohja[y][x] != '*') laby->pohja[y][x] = '-';
        depth++;

        if(y == 0 || y+1 == laby->h || x == 0 || x+1 == laby->w) {
            found++;
            if(depth < min_path) min_path = depth;
            if(found >= goals) {
                std::cout << min_path << std::endl;
                break;
            }
            laby->pohja[y][x] = '-';

            goto back_track;
        }
        else
        {
            b = 0;
            if(laby->pohja[y+1][x  ] == '.') { monovector r; r.push_back(y+1); r.push_back(x); openList.push_back(r); b=1; }
            if(laby->pohja[y  ][x+1] == '.') { monovector r; r.push_back(y); r.push_back(x+1); openList.push_back(r); b=1; }
            if(laby->pohja[y-1][x  ] == '.') { monovector r; r.push_back(y-1); r.push_back(x); openList.push_back(r); b=1; }
            if(laby->pohja[y  ][x-1] == '.') { monovector r; r.push_back(y); r.push_back(x-1); openList.push_back(r); b=1; }
            if(!b)
            {
back_track:     while(closedList.size() > 0)
                {
                    //std::cout << closedList.size() << std::endl;
                    int c_y = closedList.back()[0]; int c_x = closedList.back()[1];
                    int o_y = openList.back()[0];   int o_x = openList.back()[1];

                    laby->pohja[y][x] = '*';

                    y = c_y; x = c_x;

                    laby->pohja[y][x] = '*';

                    if( (c_y+1 == o_y && c_x   == o_x) ||
                        (c_y   == o_y && c_x+1 == o_x) ||
                        (c_y-1 == o_y && c_x   == o_x) ||
                        (c_y   == o_y && c_x-1 == o_x) )
                    {
                        laby->pohja[y][x] = '-';
                        y = o_y; x = o_x;
                        closedList.pop_back();
                        depth--;
                        break;
                    }
                    else {
                        closedList.pop_back();
                        depth--;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return min_path;
}

int main()
{
    int h, w, goals = 0;
    std::cin >> h >> w;

    laby_t *laby;
    laby = laby_allocate(h, w);

    for(int i = 0; i < laby->h; i++)
        std::cin >> laby->pohja[i];

    for(int i = 1; i < laby->h-1; i++) {
        if(laby->pohja[i][0] == '.') goals++;
        if(laby->pohja[i][laby->w-1] == '.') goals++;
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < laby->w-1; i++) {
        if(laby->pohja[0][i] == '.') goals++;
        if(laby->pohja[laby->h-1][i] == '.') goals++;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < laby->h; i++)
        for(int j = 0; j < laby->w; j++) {
            if(laby->pohja[i][j] == 'X') {
                wander(i, j, laby, goals);
                goto _exit;
            }
        }

_exit:

    //system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

I have done my homework concerning the errorsignals, and in case you guys don't know about it: http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/C++Signals.html

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first step should be to compile with debugging information and debug the code so you at least know which line is causing you the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The code compiles cleanly on a Mac OS X 10.7.5 with G++ 4.7.1, which is good:

```
g++ -g -Wall -Wextra laby.cpp -o laby
```

Unfortunately, when the result is run under `valgrind`, it produces:

```
==15030== Invalid write of size 1
==15030==    at 0x306BE: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator>><char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char*) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==15030==    by 0x10000117D: main (laby.cpp:113)
==15030==  Address 0x10001632c is 0 bytes after a block of size 12 alloc'd
==15030==    at 0xB823: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:266)
==15030==    by 0x5768D: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==15030==    by 0x576DA: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.0.9.dylib)
==15030==    by 0x1000008C0: laby_allocate(int, int) (laby.cpp:21)
==15030==    by 0x100001146: main (laby.cpp:110)
```

So, there is a problem with the memory allocation in the `laby_allocate()` function.  Or several...

```
laby_t *laby_allocate (int r, int c)
{
    laby_t *laby;
    int i;

    laby = new laby_t[sizeof (laby_t)];
```

This line allocates an array of `laby_t`; it allocates as many elements in the array as there are bytes in a `laby_t`.  This is not what you needed.

```
    laby = new laby_t;
```

Continuing:

```
    laby->pohja = new char *[r];
    for (i = 0; i < r; i++)
    {
        laby->pohja[i] = new char[c];
    }
```

This does not allocate enough space for the null at the end of the data...which is why the 'write' is 1 byte.  Change the `c` to `c+1` and `valgrind` gives a clean bill of health.

```
    laby->h = r;
    laby->w = c;

    return laby;
}
```

The answer given is `15`; I'm not convinced that's correct.

Comment: Ah! Yes, allocation is not yet my strongest point. I'll see into my code as I get back home.

Answer (score 2):

This line overflows your memory allocation.  If the user enters *w* characters, then *(w+1)* characters will be needed to hold the null-terminated string.

```
    std::cin >> laby->pohja[i];
```

This line is also allocating an array of many `laby_t` objects, though you seem to want only one.  Perhaps you confused C++ `new` with C `malloc`.

```
laby = new laby_t[sizeof (laby_t)];
```

You can replace it with this.

```
laby = new laby_t;
```

This also seems to be a remnant of C.  It's not a bug, but it unnecessarily pollutes the current namespace with reduntant symbols.

```
typedef struct _laby_t { ... } laby_t;
```

You can replace it with this.

```
struct laby_t { ... };
```

Comment: I am a bit unfamiliar with structs so as long as my debugger doesn't go boom, I wouldn't notice :D allocation too: I had to copy a snippet of code which used malloc, but since it didn't do with g++ I had to give it up and try the other way. Thank you! Very helpful. I'll see into my code as fast as I get back home.